# What's the name of my notification?

Tags: power-management, notification

I have some notifications (IDK how it's called, I'm pretty new to Ubuntu) in the screenshot posted here and I know the power manager I'm using is turning my screen off after 10 minutes of inactivity. I want to tweak the settings, but I don't even know how is the power manager called. Can you please tell me also how can I find any notification name?

[image: Notification image]

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower. I think you are wanting to change the settings in your screen saver, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what you are looking exactly but you can find the power manager in system settings. Click the power on/off button at the top right of the screen, choose System settings -> Hardware -> Power.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It was the power manager xfce4. Anyways, thanks for your answer.